# Redirect to a custom URL after login in NEXT-AUTH

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

How to redirect to a custom URL after login with next-auth?

I have one page for login and content. The logic is this:

- If user logged in -> display page content
- if user is not logged in -> display a login form on that same page.

After login the user should be redirected to the same page he logged in from and not the previous he came from to it

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the `SignIn` and `SignOut` function with the redirect paths as a parameter like so:

```
import { signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

signIn({ callbackUrl: "/app" })

signOut({ callbackUrl: "/login" });
```

Comment: The first argument of the `signIn` function should either be `undefined` or the **name** of your provider as a string.

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer is to redirect on the page once you are authenticated.

If your page that includes the authentication flow (i.e. siginIn()) is called Auth.tsx, include the following code:

```
// Authentication Redirect
const router = useRouter()
const {data: session} = useSession()

if (session) {
    router.push('/')
}
```

Then once the user lands back on that page and is authenticated, they will automatically be redirected.

Answer (score -1):

Something You might find usefull. I've used it to redirect automatically between pages.

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function foo() {
    const history = useHistory()
    
    // usage:
    history.push('url_to_redirect_to')
    // example: history.push('/') or history.push('/about')
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think this will work with next-auth. We need server side render

Comment: This also uses `react-router-dom`, which is not recommended as Next.js provides its [own router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router).